# Z-Smith Normal Form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, smith-normal-form

I am a bit confused on how to put the matrix \begin{bmatrix}4&2&4\\3&3&4\\2&2&2\end{bmatrix} in $\mathbb{Z}$-Smith Normal Form.

I know this can be done using unimodular elementary row and column operations, but everytime i've tried I end up with the wrong answer.

Any help will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The Smith normal form of that matrix is $$\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&2}.$$
That the top left value is going to be $1$ is pretty obvious; just subtract the second row of the original matrix from the first.

Answer (score -2):

I perform a series of row and column operations to get
$$\begin{pmatrix}
2&0&0\\
0&2&0\\
0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Is this your right answer ?

Comment: I dont actually have the answer, that was what i ended up with once but then I thought it was wrong since 2 does not divide 1

Comment: Thats a small point, and actually I ought to have written it as Marc did below. You can always change the order.